# Is there a way to get Go module's full path inside Go code

Tags: go, path

Is there a way that I can get the full path of a module, under external libraries, that my project is using?

Comment: Could you point the use case for this requirement?

Comment: Probably not, but what do you mean? What do you think "the full path of a module" would look like?

Comment: I imported a pkg that I need to compile while running my code. @DevendraMukharaiya

Comment: This is the full path "~/workspace/pkg/mod/github.com/spacemeshos/go-spacemesh-mock@v0.0.0-20191020144922-ca780c919bc3" just another folder on my PC.

Comment: Okay, then the answer is no; you cannot retrieve that from inside Go.

Comment: Why do you want this? This seems a lot like an XY Problem.

Comment: Like I mentioned before, I'm trying to compile an imported package. I need the full path in order to go build it.

Answer (score 1):

Go is a compiled language, and most external libraries (modules) will be statically linked into the same binary. This means all Go libraries you are using are inside the same binary, and not in your PC.

If you are using `go mod`, [this post](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules) will help you understand where the modules are located during build time.
If you are using GOPATH alone, the libraries will be downloaded into your `$GOPATH/src` followed by the address used fot the import.

If this is not what you are looking for, one way to analyze the libraries you used would be to check you `go.mod` file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I am using go mod and I do see the code on my laptop.        
I guess I would have to read from the mod file though I wanted not to have to do this, it's less elegant.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get go modules full path inside go code

No.